# Sphinx enable STP_MATCH_EXTENDED for PDO connection

Tags: pdo, sphinx

If my PDO connection is as below:

```
$sphinx = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=127.0.0.1;port=9306;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$sphinx->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$sphinx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$sphinx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And my query is:

```
$array = $sphinx->prepare("select * from `indexname` where MATCH @(title,body) hello world");
```

What is the correct way to enable SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED?

If I add:

```
require ("sphinxapi.php");
$sphinx = new SphinxClient();
$sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$sphinx->SetArrayResult(true);
```

Under the PDO connection, is this the correct way to enable stp_match_extended for PDO?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct way to enable SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED?

SphinxQL uses **Extended Match Mode** by default.

Don't need to do anything to use it.

You can change to use a different match mode if really want, but its **NOT** recommended. Internally Sphinx only (now!) implements Extended match mode, the others are all emulated.